# Estimating the probability of a failure

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

We are estimating the spares requirement for a radar power supply. The power supply was designed with a mean ($\mu$) life of $6500$ hours. The standard deviation ($\sigma$) determined from testing is $750$ hours. What is the likelihood that a power supply would fail between $7225$ and $7500$ hours?

a. $0.4082$ or $40.82\%$

b. $0.0742$ or $7.42\%$

c. $0.3340$ or $33.40\%$

d  $0.1066$ or $10.66\%$

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? And do you know what distribution the RV is?

Comment: Is the life time of the power supply normally distributed?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the answer is A 40.82%

Comment: Could you please assist in this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

Experiment: Randomly select one power supply

Random Variable $L$: Power Supply $L$ifetime

Possible Values $l$: [0 hours,1300 hours]

Determine: $P$($7,225 \le$ $L$ $\le$ $7,550$) $=$ $P$($\dfrac{7,225-6,500}{750}$ $\le$ $Z$ $\le$$\dfrac{7,500-6,500}{750}$)

$=$ $P$(0.97 $\le$ $Z$ $\le$ $1.33$) $= 0.9082 - 0.8340 =0.0742. $

[image]